# How to listen to events in Angular2 template?

Tags: angular

This code will fire foo(bar) on click event

`<li (click)="foo(bar)"></li>`

I tried to use

```
(focus)="foo()"
```

and

```
(blur)="foo()"
```

but it doesnt work.

1) Where can I find a list of implemented eventlisteners in template?

2) If click and keyUp are the only event listeners that I can call in template, whats' the pattern for handling other event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Angular 2 template-basics](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html#!#template-basics) Angular 2 supports all dom events in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Here's an example of focus working:  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tf7bkjVQUy3LMhdCqjCz?p=preview)

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" (focus)="focused()">

focused(){
   alert('focused');
 }
```